# How to query mongo using the $in operator when string includes ~ from php

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with mongo queries:

- string can contain special characters like ~
- I'm forced to use $in operators
- need to find all objects with an element in an array.
- i'm using php

Those string can have the ~ character (mongo doesn't read it well, it returns null). and maybe other characters

I've tried everything when creating the array with strings (htmlspecialchars, urlencode) and doesn't return object when the string contains ~

```
$db->products->find(array("url" => array('$in'=>$array1), "shop"=>$shop));
```

and $array1 =

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> string(60) "http://www.example.com/rasdas-~--m083.html" 
[1]=> string(48) "http://www.example.com//bluzasml-3302-alb.html" 
[2]=> string(52) "http://www.example.com/123/asdasstru.html" 
[3]=> string(44) "http://www.example.com/gean21210-verde.html" 
[4]=> string(45) "http://www.example.com/wer/34k2k--red-ego.html" 
[5]=> string(74) "http://www.example.com/ro/quiksil-~--cbd-~-gri-~-4991~sud724.html"
```

}

Doesn't return the objects for 1st and last, even if in the database they are exactly like that.

Comment: I don't have this problem. MongoDB is quite happy with matching the `~` character and there is no reason it should have a problem. Perhaps there was some strange encoding done when the documents were inserted. But inserted directly in the shell or as PHP code I see no problem. Maybe your "shop" condition is not valid for those documents?

Comment: I've tried the query directly into the console and returns nothing. My feeling is about a character encoding which doesn't match the database. I can't see which...

Comment: Encoding may well be the case, but we certainly cannot see that from what you have posted here. At any rate, if there is some strange encoding on the stored data then any string you send in to query would need to be encoded in the same way for it to match. But a standard tilde `~` does not require any special encoding as it is ASCII and actually valid for a URI scheme. Maybe your question needs to show the data as retrieved from the shell, if it is indeed any different.

Comment: What happens if you remove the $in condition and just matches it to one of those strings? There is no reason why this doesn't work, so there are other things at play here then what you are describing. I suggest you simplify your query to the bare minimum. If it still doesn't work then please post an complete example document, along with an actual query and the result of var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));